# Cannot resolve "rbenv init" instruction for zsh and oh-my-zsh on Mac

Tags: ruby, zsh, rbenv, oh-my-zsh

I'm a Ruby developer setting up my local development environment on a new iMac running macOS High Sierra with iTerm2, Homebrew, rbenv, zsh and oh-my-zsh.

I used RVM before on my Linux machine, but want to switch to rbenv with this iMac because I've heard it's better in some ways, so I'm trying to make sure all is as it should be with my rbenv setup before I start downloading/installing Rails and other gems.

I'm running `rbenv init`, which, as I understand it, will tell me what I need to do next to get rbenv working. It displays this message:

```
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

So I went into my `.zshrc` file and added that line. My `.zshrc` file currently looks exactly like this (comments omitted):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export ZSH="/Users/christian/.oh-my-zsh"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

No matter how many times I restart my iTerm terminal and run `rbenv init`, it always gives me that same instruction, and nothing else.

The first line in the file used to be: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` but I changed it to the current line because another StackOverflow page suggested this to someone having a very similar problem, but it didn't help.

I don't understand why it keeps telling me to add something that's already in the `.zshrc` file, and I don't know whether I've successfully setup rbenv with everything and am ready to start developing in Ruby on Rails.

I've looked at lots of stuff about this on here and other sites, but I can't seem to find the answer. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me why it keeps giving me that same message? how I make it proceed with the instructions and tell me the next thing to do? and how I'll be able to tell for sure when my rbenv is properly setup for development?

Comment: You don't need to invoke `rbenv init` anymore. Take a look at `rbenv help` for the list of things you can do now. The next step is probably something along the lines of `rbenv install 2.7.2`.

Comment: I eventually ran `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash` and it showed green for everything. I also tested some commands and I can install and switch between global and local versions fine, and the current version shown with `ruby -v` always reflects my latest selection. I think you're right, it's already finished and setup so I don't need `rbenv init` anymore. I was confused because it kept telling me to do something I'd already done, so I thought it hadn't worked. It would be more helpful if it said "setup completed" or something :(  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually ran `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash` and it showed green for everything. It seems I had everything already setup correctly; the `rbenv init` interface was just confusingly telling me to do something I'd already done. I confirmed it was all working by downloading different versions of Ruby with `rbenv install`, switching between them with `rbenv local` and `rbenv global`, and making sure `ruby -v` always displayed whatever version I had selected.